# Regex optionally extracting characters between two characters

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following string `thisIs/My-7777-Any-other-text` it also is possible for the following `thisIs/My-7777`

I am looking to extract `My-777` in both scenarios using regex. So essentially I am looking to extract everything between the first forward flash and the second hyphen (Second hyphen may not exist). I tried the following regex which wasn't quite right

```
(?<=\/)(.*)(?=-)
```

Comment: Use `(?<=\/)[^-]*-[^-]*`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fwWXZ1/1). Or with lazy matching and a Lookahead: `(?<=\/).*?-.*?(?=-|$)`.

Comment: Can you have something like `111/thisIs/My-7777-more-text`, `111/thisIs/My-7777-more-text/end`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a capture group

```
^[^\/]*\/([^-]*-[^-]*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\/]*\/`
- `(` Capture group

  - `[^-]*-[^-]*` Match a `-` between optional chars that are not `-`
- `)` Close capture group

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JTvbou/1)

Without an anchor, and not allowing `/` before and after `-`

```
[^\/]*\/([^-\/]*-[^-\/]*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vbpAlI/1)

Comment: Actually, [`(?<=\/)[^-]+-[^-]+`](https://regex101.com/r/uMxxBb/2) seems enough.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You could also do that, but in that case I think I would go for `(?<=\/)[^\n-\/]+-[^\n-\/]+` https://regex101.com/r/yYZk1t/1 to not match any `/`'s. You can post yours of course :-)

Answer (score 0):

If we take into account the structure of your current input strings, you can use

```
(?<=\/)[^-]+-[^-]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uK4K4V/1/).

If your strings are more complex and look like `thisIs/My-7777/more-text-here`, and you actually want to match from the first `/`, then you may use

```php
^[^\/]+\/\K[^\/-]+-[^\/-]+       ## PHP, PCRE, Boost (Notepad++), Onigmo (Ruby)
(?<=^[^\/]+\/)[^\/-]+-[^\/-]+  ## JS (except IE & Safari), .NET, Python PyPi regex)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uK4K4V/2/) or [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uK4K4V/3). Note `\n` is added in the demo since the input is a single multiline string, in real life input, if a newline char is expected, use it in each negated character class to keep matching on the one line.

Answer (score 0):

This one is working for me,  Try it with case insensitive ticked

Find what: `.*?/|-any.*`
Replace with: `blank`

Output should be ↠↠  `My-7777`